# Finding previous trading day in pandas is very slow

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, trading

I have this `df`

```
data1_txt = """
date
7/8/2021
7/6/2021
6/29/2021
"""
```

I need to get the previous trading day. I manage to do it with `pandas_market_calendars` python package. Here is my whole code

```
import io
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data1_txt = """
date
7/8/2021
7/6/2021
6/29/2021
"""
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data1_txt))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
holidays = nyse.holidays()
holidays = list(holidays.holidays)
US_BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays)
df['date_prev'] = df['date'] - 1 * US_BUSINESS_DAY
```

The code does the job. But the process is very slow for a large dataset. Is it possible to somehow increase the code speed?

P.S. When I run the code python gives me this warning:

```
PerformanceWarning: Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex
  warnings.warn(
```

Comment: Doesn't nyse.holidays() already return the CustomBusinessDay that you want?

Comment: @Stryder no i get  `'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.CustomBusinessDay' object is not iterable` error if I don't have `holidays = list(holidays.holidays)` line

Comment: @Stryder you were right `US_BUSINESS_DAY = nyse.holidays()` does the job. But as you have said it does not solves the problem. The real problem is the last line `df['date_prev'] = df['date'] - 1 * US_BUSINESS_DAY`. I need to get vectorized DateOffset , but i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found a way, it makes use of [np.busday_offset](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_offset.html)

```
def other(df):
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
    holidays = nyse.holidays().holidays  

    # check out the docs for how to adjust roll to your preference
    result = np.busday_offset(df["date"].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),     
             [-1], roll= "forward",  weekmask= "1111100", holidays= holidays)
    return result
```

After creating a df with 10,000 rows of random dates and passing it to your and to `other` function. The speed went from

> Stat(s) for 10 execution(s) of yours: 
> mean:   893.01282 ms 
> median:   883.1989 ms 
> stdv:   83.3837 ms 
> max:   1134.7835 ms 
> min:   760.0869 ms

to:

> Stat(s) for 10 execution(s) of other:
> mean:   278.60783 ms 
> median:   274.44165 ms 
> stdv:   27.9785 ms 
> max:   330.3079 ms 
> min:   235.4329 ms

And with your code:

```
data1_txt = """
date
7/8/2021
7/6/2021
6/29/2021
"""
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data1_txt))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def yours(df):
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
    holidays = nyse.holidays()
    holidays = list(holidays.holidays)
    US_BUSINESS_DAY = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays)
    result =  df['date'] - 1 * US_BUSINESS_DAY
    return result


display(yours(df), other(df))
>>> 
0   2021-07-07
1   2021-07-02
2   2021-06-28
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

array(['2021-07-07', '2021-07-02', '2021-06-28'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: Thank you, looks very promising. But I could not replicate your code, i have this error `TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: Did you change the datetime column to be date? `df["date"].dt.date`

Comment: Yes, I did `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date`

Comment: I did this, `dates_input = df3["date"].values.astype('datetime64[D]')` and `nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
holidays = nyse.holidays().holidays  
df3['date_prev'] = np.busday_offset(dates_input, [-1], roll= "forward",  
             weekmask= "1111100", holidays= holidays)`  and it worked

Comment: Could you please check if what I did is correct, and if correct to could you please add it to your response. If you think it is correct I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: that is correct and actually makes it a bit better :)

Comment: I added it to the `other` function!

Comment: This is what is called efficiency, your code is 24 times faster than my initial code.